# Hinge Type for Garage Cabinet

Tags: hinges

I’m thinking about making a simple garage shelf out of 2x4’s with the 2” side facing forward. It won’t have side walls or a back so will essentially be four 2x4’s with some shelving on it.

If I want to put doors on it, how do I know which hinge to get? I want full overlay doors and I think I’d use 3/4” ply for them. Can I use any full overlay hinge? Based on my research a standard full overlay hinge is made to overlay 3/4” side panels however mine will be 2 inches.

I’m a new woodworker and this will be my first build with doors.

Looking for guidance on this.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WSE. A sketch of your project might generate more ideas.

Comment: Have you considered plain old butt hinges? They would make all your concerns moot.

Comment: How does one put doors on a shelf? I'd really like to see a sketch of this

Answer (score 1):

Many makers of full overlay hinges with different details. Consult diagram for each hinge. For some there is max/min thickness for door, but no max for sides.

> I’m a new woodworker and this will be my first build with doors.

Full overlay hinges are not simple to fit perfectly and most require large Forstner bit to drill cup hole, which is maybe expensive. For simple garage cabinet other hinge types are good choice -- cheaper, will make installation easier and quicker + no loss of internal space.

[Choosing The Right Cabinet Hinge For Your Project](https://www.rockler.com/learn/choosing-the-right-hinge-for-your-project)
[Choosing Cabinet Door Hinges](https://sawdustgirl.com/choosing-cabinet-door-hinges/)
[18 Different Types of Cabinet Hinges](https://www.homestratosphere.com/types-of-cabinet-hinges/)

Comment: Your statement about not having a max thickness for the sides is what I’m struggling with. I’m assuming that the thickness of the side walls would affect where the offset hole is drilled on the door, especially for full overlay doors. The thicker the side wall, the greater the offset would need to be from the door edge. How would I figure out what the offset is and where to drill the hole for the hinge on the door ?

Comment: @EdS, I'm not familiar with all full-overlay hinge designs — here, a very generic type is used almost everywhere...... I can go down to my kitchen to see exactly that :-) and for those side-wall thickness is irrelevant. Think about where two cabinets are mounted side by side, effectively making those sides 1 1/4" thick. But seriously let me be the 3rd to suggest you sidestep this worry and just use a different hinge! Unless you plan to do a lot of similar hinges in your immediate future the cost of that Forstner/wave-edge/sawtooth bit is money you'd be better off investing in something else...

Comment: If you look at [diagram](https://www.hafele.ie/INTERSHOP/static/WFS/Haefele-HIR-Site/-/Haefele/en_IE/pim/images/huge/mont-04088145.jpg) for most full overlay hinges only relative position of **surface** of sides to door matters, so thickness of sides not important.

Comment: have you looked at price of good Ø35mm Forstner bit? Not safe to drill these holes freehand so if you do not own drill press + drilling guide.

Comment: I'll chime in to suggest that if the OP is planning on building some cabinetry for the kitchen or bathroom, the garage furniture is the _perfect_ place to practice installing these hinges and that _now_ is the time to go ahead and make the tool investment! Of course, that's _only_ if there are reasonably concrete plans to do more of this work, otherwise, it may well lead to frustration and wasted money.

Comment: @VolframK Look at that diagram and consider that the OP seems to want the "door overlay" distance to be 1.5". I don't think I've ever seen a euro-style hinge that can accommodate that.

Comment: @VolframK, I know Kreg make a jig for drilling the holes and that was what I was planning to use. I do have forstner bits but from what I’ve seen the Kreg jig acts as a kind of drill press.

Comment: Maybe it’s time to do some experimenting. As @FreeMan pointed out, it’s garage furniture so a good place to try. 

Thanks all for your inputs